# Prove "Infinite Sets Contain Countably Infinite Subsets" without Using Axiom of Choice.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know how to prove "Infinite Sets Contain Countably Infinite Subsets". But I found that I have to use some kind of AC (at least DC or ACω). I read that in analysis the statement that can be proved by using AC can also be proved without using AC. Is there a way to prove this statement without using AC?

P.S.: Sorry, I didn't pose my complete logic so the "Dedekind" is a mis-input. "Infinite Set" here I mean is the opposite of "Finite Set", so please don't assume the infinite set is defined as Dedekind infinite. My complete logic is to use this fact as the lemma to prove that Dedekind infinite is equivalent to infinite. I appreciate for the nice answer given below, but that's not what I need. Description is edited already.

Comment: [Accordingly to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set#Dedekind-infinite_sets_in_ZF) the answer is positive.

Comment: It's not the case that *every* statement in analysis that can be proved with AC can also be proved without it. By [Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem), that's true for first-order statements about the reals of a particular maximum complexity, $\Sigma^1_3$ sentences specifically.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but now it's a duplicate of a whole other question. But you got an answer by Wojowu below. You *can't* prove this equivalence without using the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a Dedekind infinite set. By definition, there is a function $f\colon A\to A$ which puts $A$ in bijection with a proper subset $B\subsetneq A$. Let $x\in A\setminus B$. Define $g\colon \mathbb{N}\to A$ by $g(n) = f^n(x)$.

Now it's not hard to show that $g$ is injective, so $\text{im}(g)$ is a countably infinite subset of $A$.

Note that I didn't use AC when I picked $x\in A\setminus B$. The existence of such an $x$, and hence of the function $g$, follows immediately from the fact that $B$ is a proper subset of $A$.

Comment: Thanks~! I really appreciate for your answer. But I apologize for that I didn't pose my description clear enough. It's edited.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. It is consistent with ZF that there is an infinite set of *reals* which doesn't contain a countable subset, as was shown by Paul Cohen. This shows that it cannot be proven in ZF, even for subsets of reals, which is precisely what we would (generally) care about in analysis.

Comment: The set of reals you refer to is infinite, but *Dedekind finite*. The question is about Dedekind infinite sets.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ah, sorry; I have misread the question as asking about "Dedekind finite".

Comment: Oh, could you show me that example (infinite set of reals which doesn't contain a countable subset)? That's exactly what I need~!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry, I didn't pose my question clear enough. It's edited. Wojuwu's interpretation is the one I need.